# grapes js. insert Traits Manager into StyleManager

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, grapesjs

I using `grapes.js` editor and I would like in one column insert `StyleManager` and Traits Manager. How is this possible?
My code:

```js
styleManager: {
    traitsManager: {},
        sectors: [{
            open: true,
            buildProps: ['text-align', 'width', 'height', 'max-width', 'min-height', 'margin', 'font-family', 'font-size', 'font-weight', 
            'letter-spacing', 'color', 'line-height', 'text-decoration', 'font-style','background-color','background'],
            property: 'text-align',
            defaults: 'left',
            properties: [{
                property: 'text-align',
                list: [
                    { value: 'left'},
                    { value: 'center'},
                    { value: 'right'}               
                ]
            }]
    }],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, can do that.

HTML

```
 <div>
      <div id="selectors-container" />
      <div id="style-manager-container" />
      <div id="traits-container" />
 </div>
```

JS

```
       styleManager: {
          appendTo: document.querySelector('#style-manager-container'),   
        },
        selectorManager: {
          appendTo: document.querySelector('#selectors-container'),
        },
        traitManager: {
          appendTo: document.querySelector('#traits-container'),
        },
```